# Xamarin.Forms: Changing Font Size and Font Color of a Chart

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

Good Day Everyone. I'm currently creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application. 
I was able to display a Chart using OxyPlot. But I want to make it more presentable by designing it.

Do you know how am I going to change the color and font size of the PlotModel Title and the Label per PieSlice. What code should I add? And if you can suggest what more can I add to my Chart, that would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Here's my code:

```
 public PieViewModel()
    {

        modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1"};

        dynamic seriesP1 = new PieSeries { StrokeThickness = 2.0, InsideLabelPosition = 0.8, AngleSpan = 360, StartAngle = 0 };

        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false, Fill = OxyColors.PaleVioletRed });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = true });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157) { IsExploded = true });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = true });
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 35) { IsExploded = true });

        modelP1.Series.Add(seriesP1);
        this.SalesModel = modelP1;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, OxyPlot doesn't support individual styling for single PieSlice labels. However, you can change the font and text color for all of them collectively. All the properties you need to set can be found from the PlotModel class:

- **TitleColor** (OxyColor)
- **TitleFont** (String)

AND

- **LegendTextColor** (OxyColor)
- **LegendTitleColor** (OxyColor)
- **LegendFont** (String)
- **LegendTitleFont** (String)

The Font properties are of type String and need the name of the font family you want to use.

Look around the [PlotModel](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/PlotModel/PlotModel.cs) class and you'll find many other styling options.

Comment: Sir how will I add this code to my code to change my title color?  this.TitleColor = OxyColors.Automatic;

Comment: If you don't define the title color, it's OxyColors.Automatic by default. Try this when you're creating a new instance of the PlotModel class to see a change: `modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1", TitleColor = OxyColors.Gold};`

Comment: Alright, noted Sir. How about the Pie slices? What code should I add in my program?

Comment: With the same logic you just add more stuff to the PlotModel initialization. `modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1", TitleColor = OxyColors.Gold, LegendTextColor = OxyColors.Blue, LegendFont = "FONTFAMILY" /* etc */ };`

Comment: The LegentTextColor and the LegendFont does not make any changes to my labels Sir

Comment: What about LegendTitleColor and LegendTitleFont? I'm sure there's a way to change them but can't test it now myself.

Comment: Sir it doesn't affect my Labels either.

Comment: Sorry, I confused legend with the axis labels. Could you try TextColor and DefaultFont? `modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1", TitleColor = OxyColors.Gold, TextColor = OxyColors.Blue, DefaultFont = "FONTFAMILY" /* etc */ };`

Comment: only the TextColor worked Sir. The DefaultFont didn't worked. How can I enlarge the size of the Text?

Comment: Font and size are changed separately. DefaultFontSize will let you change the size.

Comment: I do it like this but it didn't work also. The font doesn't get larger : modelP1 = new PlotModel
            {
                Title = "Sales Per Product",
                TitleColor = OxyColors.Teal,
                TitleFontSize = 30,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                DefaultFont = "Arial Black",
                DefaultFontSize = 20
               
            };

Comment: Looks like I'm reading the code wrong, don't really have time to dive too deeply into it. There are a few other FontSize properties you could try but if none of them work, I'm afraid that font size changes are not supported for labels. You could however fork the source code on GitHub and extend it to support label size changes (in case it's not supported already). The code is really clean and easy to read.

Comment: alright Sir, can I still ask some questions regarding Xamarin.Forms? Maybe you can give me your email?

Comment: I suggest you to ask the questions here so that everyone else can benefit from the answers. I'm also very busy so it's better to have multiple people who can answer your questions. :) Just create a new question and we'll see what's up!

Comment: Alright Sir. Is it possible for me to mention you in my Questions?

Comment: I'd say it's better to mention this specific thread if needed for reference. Mentioning a specific user doesn't help much in this case.